# Can I copy a URL from Safari address bar as percent-encoded string?

Tags: safari, encoding, url

What Safari currently does is quite annoying, it copies the URLs as-is, for example:

[https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/中國](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B)

While I understand why Safari does it (for human readability), many applications have issue dealing with UTF-8 in URL (Twitter, for example).

I prefer Chrome's behavior, where URL is copied as percent-encoded string (only the UTF-8 part, ASCII is copied as-is, this approach is likely chosen for compatibility):

https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B

Can I do this in Safari without resorting to URL encoded manually?

Comment: peculiar that if you right click a link-> share-> messages-> it shows both formats. SO what you can do as a workaround is click the share icon in the top right corner(if done so in preferences) and tap messages. Then copy the link from there. I know it is a bit long but let's wait for an answer